# PHP detect country regardless of proxy

Tags: php, proxy, country

I would like to detect a user's country or country code regardless if they are using a proxy. I don't necessarily need to use PHP to accomplish this. I was hoping I could pull out a constant from the computer and I'm not very knowledgeable about proxies. The end result is to block anyone from ordering from my store who is not sitting on a computer in the US. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that.

- You can't be sure what country from is user
- You can't be sure if he is using proxy
- You can't be sure if he is using computer device
- You can't be sure that he is human.

Comment: People nowadays want to launch rockets to the outer space with PHP/Java/C# ... :) +1 for this answer

Comment: The Prodigy are owning the universe for 23 years, they are allowed to do that :))

Comment: Thanks. Never got this to work. I was offering coupon codes on checkout against the MSRP of a Chinese manufacturer and didn't want them to see it. They were very unhappy :3